# difference between two Python statements

Tags: python

How are these two Python statements different:

```
>>> if a==1 and b==2:
        pass
>>> if a==1:
        if b==2:
            pass
```

Comment: The first looks neater... That's about it

Answer (score 2):

If these two statements are the entire code (e.g., there's no `else` to match the `if`), these two statements will have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

There is no practical difference.  Both must evaluate `a==1` and `b==2` for `pass` to execute, and both "short-circuit" and do not evaluate `b==2` if `a==1` is `False`.

Here's an example of short-circuiting:

```
>>> a=1
>>> b=2
>>> if a==1 and b==2:
...   print('pass')
...
pass
```

Here, the first statement is True so the second is evaluated, but `c` does not exist:

```
>>> if a==1 and c==2:
...   print('pass')
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
>>> if a==1:
...   if c==2:
...     print('pass')
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

Here, the first statement is false so the invalid variable is not evaluated:

```
>>> a=2
>>> if a==1 and c==2:
...   print('pass')
...
>>>
>>> if a==1:
...   if c==2:
...     print('pass')
...
>>>
```